# Why does the 'like' count in my page rollback?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm attempting to implement facebook "likes" and having a bit of trouble.  The count keeps rolling back after a page refresh.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Navigate to http://bookmill.co.kr/books/9/quotations/79  (*note: this page is in Korean*)
2. Click Like
3. Notice the like count increments
4. Refresh your browsers

Notice that after step #4 the count is rolled back?   The like is posted to my Facebook wall. I'm not clear what's going wrong.

I attempted the same thing with: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
 and it's rollback too.

Any idea what's going on?  `og` tag is wrong? incorrect `AppId`?

Answer (score 0):

[facebooklikes](http://www.socialmediamarketingmall.com/facebook-likes): Well, developer.facebook has limitation. So you probably need to hire an expert in programming.